# Async Controller and questions everywhere

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I Have a quick question about async Controller and Actions in ASP.Net MVC 4+ (using the async/await programming model returning a Task   ).
What do i risk if all my actions are async even if the underline operations are not IO Bound (for example slow web service or network communication ) and can be CPU Bound. I mean all my actions will be async no matter what code is int it . I Hope i'am clear.

Will be performance problems due to synchronisation context overhead or any other significant overhead for a public website that can have a lot of simultanous users ?

Thank you for your futur answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What do i risk if all my actions are async even if the underline operations are not IO Bound (for example slow web service or network communication ) and can be CPU Bound.

This is exactly what you *don't* want to do.

Consider what happens with a synchronous action: the request comes in, ASP.NET allocates a thread for that request, and that thread executes the action. When the action is complete, that same thread sends the response.

Now consider what happens if you "offload" an action's CPU-bound work to the thread pool (e.g., `Task.Run`). The request comes in, ASP.NET allocates a thread for that request, and the thread starts executing the action. When the thread hits `Task.Run`, it allocates *another* thread from the thread pool to execute the CPU-bound code. Then the asynchronous action method hits the `await` for that task, so the original thread is returned to the ASP.NET runtime. The *other* thread then finishes the work and continues on to send the response.

So, you're doing *more* work for every request if you have an asynchronous action that pushes CPU-bound work to the thread pool. You should *never* do this on ASP.NET.

I explain this in more detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will run into any problems for a simple app since the async workers are running off a pool of threads with a limit number of threads. But what you may run into is a condition where the client HTTP threads are waiting on the asyn response and it exceeds a network gateway timeout. For instance, amazon ELB have a 60 second timeout. So clients can be disconnected while the async task is still running. If that happens a lot then you could end up with a lot of async tasks running and completing with no client to respond to. That would be an unfortunate condition because your clients are not getting data and your server is working for nothing.

One thing I would consider is whether or not you need async calls. I would suggest tuning up your service calls and making sure they are fast enough to address load instead of making the front end async as a workaround for the latency. For instance, using caching. Just a suggestion.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So the task has to take more than 60s so the clients disconnect right ?